# How to pass a Box value to a function

Tags: rust

If I have the following method:

```
fn borrow_func(c: Box<i32>) {
    // some code
}

fn main(){
    let a = Box::new(5i32);
    let b = a;

    borrow_func(b);
    println!("b contains: {}", b);
}
```

because the resource in heap will be released in the **borrow_func**, Is there any way to avoid this?

If I try to use a borrow in the **borrow_func** like following, I will get a

compile error:

> expected `Box<i32>`,
>   found `&_`

```
fn borrow_func(&c: Box<i32>) {
}
```

It seem that the compiler do not the pointer type for **b**?

How can I make this work ?

Comment: The code you have posted compiles fine. Did you mean to post some slightly different code or is something missing?

Comment: @PeterHall I add a code to use the variable b to demonstrate the usage, Because the memory is reclaimed, so use the variable b after invoke the function borrow_func() is invalid, and this will compile failed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `borrow_func` actually takes the ownership over the boxed variable. You should change the signature of `borrow_func` to reflect the borrowing, like this:

```
fn borrow_func(c: &i32) {
    // some code
}

fn borrow_func2(c: &Box<i32>) {
    // some code
}

fn main(){
    let a = Box::new(5i32);
    let b = a;

    borrow_func(&b);
    borrow_func2(&b);
    println!("b contains: {}", b);
}
```

You can use a simple reference of an &Box as well. For more information about borrowing, check: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/references-and-borrowing.html

[Vladimir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/788207/vladimir-matveev) added a useful information:

> pointers to boxes like &Box are unidiomatic and completely pointless - they introduce unnecessary double indirection and give nothing useful back. Just plain reference (&i32) is always the way to go.

Comment: I'd add that pointers to boxes like `&Box<i32>` are unidiomatic and completely pointless - they introduce unnecessary double indirection and give nothing useful back. Just plain reference (`&i32`) is always the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, I've included your comment.

Comment: Thanks very much! Yes, in the actually, we may not use like &Box<i32>, I just try to understand Rust.